# Airflow having subdags stuck when using KubernetesExecutor

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, executor

I have setup an airflow instance on eks and I set `AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=KubernetesExecutor`. When a dag has only tasks but not a subdag then each pod is dynamically created for each tasks and runs fine but when I have a dag with multiple subdags, it does not runs the subdag and instead the first task inside the first subdag remains in the queue state.

After I set `AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor` and while creating the subdag I set `executor=KubernetesExecutor()` it works fine and tasks inside the subdags runs in separate pods. But I don't know whether I will get the same power of the `KubernetesExecutor` or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4515) reported to this problem. Unfortunately it's unsolved.

Comment: @mWatney thanks for your reply. It means if we have subdags, KubernetesExecutor will not work as expected. But what if I am use LocalExecutor on parentLevel and kubernetesExecutor on child level, it works for me but I don't know how much it will powerful.